# Create a user in the Active Directory with Command-Line

Tags: active-directory, command-line-interface

I can to add  a user in a Root-OU with dsadd command-line.But,I can't to add to in a Sub-OU.
How can I add a user to a Sub-OU with dsadd command-line?

Here is my command-line.

```
dsadd user "cn=XXXX,ou=TEST,dc=mycompany,dc=com"  -upn XXXX@mycompany.com -fn XXXX -ln     YYYY 
-display XXXXYYYY -pwd 1234567 -desc "IT PERSONAL"  -mustchpwd yes
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error.

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Comment: What are the results of running the command you have above?  Does it create the user in the root or in the test ou?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps experiment with the PowerShell option, **New-ADUser**

```
New-ADUser GlenJohn -Type iNetOrgPerson -Path "DC=AppNC" -server lds.Fabrikam.com
```

Or

```
New-ADUser GlenJohn -OtherAttributes @{title="director";mail="glenjohn@fabrikam.com"}
```

it has a **-Path** parameter which allows you to set the parent OU like so:

```
 -Path "ou=mfg,dc=noam,dc=corp,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

Comment: First of all,thanks so much.But,How can I do with dsadd command-line?

Answer (score 0):

Another nice tool using PowerShell is the Quest AD commandlets [here](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).  It lets you set the OU using -ParentContainer and has tons of other functionality as well.

```
new-qaduser -ParentContainer "ou=sales,dc=contoso,dc=com" -UserPrincipalName jimjim@contoso.com -FirstName Jim -LastName Jim
```